# BizTalk MSMQ userid and password in a bindings file

Tags: msmq, biztalk, binding

I'm setting up a solution to deploy, driven by a batch file so it's reproducible 
- I've got a binding file that works but I've now added on my MSMQ adapters
- works on my local machine, but I've found I have to add a userid and password to get it to work on the actual server
   - it's in the domain, my virtual dev machine is just workgroup

Is there someway to add the userid and password to the file ?
  - seems unlikely as that'd have the password in clear text, but what's the solution
  - I sort of think something w.r.t. SSO, but that is an area I've not been near

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the userid and password into any BizTalk binding that supports authentication, including MSMQ. For security, the password is not exported, you just get a mask.

The userName and password sections of the binding file are not exported unless they have been configured, so the simplest thing to do is configure a MSMQ send port with userName and password manually and export the bindings - this forces the elements containing userName and the masked password to be generated into the binding file.

What you are looking for in your binding file is the <TransportTypeData> element of your MSMQ send port. This contains all of your adapter config information as encoded data.

Within that element there is a userName and password section. The password will be masked out with asterisks. Put the password for the environment there and import the binding.

The part of the encoded data with username and password will look something like below:

&amp;lt;userName&amp;gt;YourUserName&amp;lt;/userName&
amp;gt;&amp;lt;password&amp;gt;******&amp;lt;/password&amp;gt;

Answer (score 2):

> For security reasons, when you export
>   bindings, BizTalk Server removes the
>   passwords for the bindings from the
>   file. After importing the bindings,
>   you must reconfigure passwords for
>   send ports and receive locations
>   before they will function. You
>   configure passwords in the Transport
>   Properties dialog box of the BizTalk
>   Server Administration console for the
>   send port or receive location. For
>   instructions, see How to Create a Send
>   Port. See also How to Create a Receive
>   Location.

*From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa558708.aspx*

If you however open the biding file and scroll down to the line with the properties for the MSMQ Adapter you'll find the empty nodes. All you then have to do is to fill these out and the right values and they will be used the next time you import the binding file.

Of course you'll have to remember to redo this every time you export a new binding ...

Comment: Thanks Richard, found the details in TransferTypeData tag in the encoded XML